# Error Converting data type varchar to numeric with reference to id

Tags: union, varchar

New to the forum, and new to sql for the most part.

I am getting an error message "Error Converting data type varchar to numeric." when i run the following script.  It is referring to the supplier_id field.

I am looking to pull all supplier_id with purchases over the time period defined (1 and 2 years), the number of lines purchased, and the total spent.

```
select supplier_id,
            sum(total_spend_last_12) as total_spend_last_12,
            sum(total_spend_last_24) as total_spend_last_24,
            count(number_lines_purchased_last_12) as number_lines_purchased_last_12,
            count(number_lines_purchased_last_24) as number_lines_purchased_last_24 

from (
select a.supplier_id,

            sum(e.extended_cost) as total_spend_last_12,
            count(e.item_id) as number_lines_purchased_last_12,
            0 as total_spend_last_24,
            0 as number_lines_purchased_last_24

from p21_view_po_hdr as a

inner join p21_view_po_line as b on b.po_no=a.po_no
inner join p21_view_supplier as c on c.supplier_id=a.supplier_id
left outer join p21_view_inventory_receipts_hdr as d on d.po_number=a.supplier_id
inner join p21_view_inventory_receipts_line as e on e.receipt_number=d.receipt_number

where e.date_created>= dateadd(day,-365,getdate()) and a.location_id='af'
group by a.supplier_id

union 

select a.supplier_id,
            0 as total_spend_last_12,
            0 as number_lines_purchased_last_12,
            sum(e.extended_cost) as total_spend_last_24,
            count(e.item_id) as number_lines_purchased_last_24

from p21_view_po_hdr as a

inner join p21_view_po_line as b on b.po_no=a.po_no
inner join p21_view_supplier as c on c.supplier_id=a.supplier_id
left outer join p21_view_inventory_receipts_hdr as d on d.po_number=a.supplier_id
inner join p21_view_inventory_receipts_line as e on e.receipt_number=d.receipt_number

where e.date_created >= dateadd(day,-720,getdate()) and a.location_id='af'
group by a.supplier_id


)as tbl
group by tbl.supplier_id
```

Comment: Is `supplier_id` a `varchar` and `po_number` a `numeric?`

Comment: they are both decimals (19,0)

Comment: It has something to do with me creating the sub table and the unions because if I just run the one set of data for year one and take out all the sub table and union script, it runs just fine....